# How to order a Public and Private Vlan using Softlayer API

Tags: java, api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I want to order a Public and Private Vlan using Rest API. I didn't find any API references related to Vlan creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the following example:

E.G 
Order private VLAN:

Method: POST

```
https://[username]:apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
```

Body

```
{  "parameters":[{  
           "complexType":"SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Vlan",
           "location":"DALLAS05",
           "quantity":1,
           "packageId":571,
           "prices":[{  
                 "id":  2019,
                 "item":{
                    "id":1072,
                    "keyName" :"PRIVATE_NETWORK_VLAN"}
                    }],
            "name":"testVlan"   
  }]}
```

to order a public VLAN is the same that order a private VLAN just you have to look for a public VLAN item price.

Keep in mind that you must choose the items according to the selected datacenter.

To get the item prices use the following REST API call.

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Product_Package/571/getItemPrices?maskObject=mask[pricingLocationGroup[locations]]
```